# How to migrate Windows 2008 r2 server to new harddisk

Tags: hard-drive

I have a HP ProLiant ML350 G6 Window 2008 R2 server, 6 x 300GB Hard disk in RAID 5, as the storage capacity is low, so I want to change to 6 x 3TB Hard disk in RAID 5,  so I want to ask how to copy the OS to the new Hard disk, the new hard disk is in GPT format, please help, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the old OS is in MBR format while the new Hard disk is in GPT format, how should i do it, i used Ghosted to copy the existing OS then ghost back to the new hard disk, but it cannot boot up the system, its stopped at the loading bar then restart and keep repeating this, anyone please guide me how to do this and any suggestion for the clone software, thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe helpfull: https://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/sln167714/windows-server-how-to-repair-the-boot-files-in-windows-server-2008-or-2008-r2-if-the-server-wont-boot?lang=en

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for me in a similar scenario:

1. Make a windows backup (to an external drive) with Windows Backup Server service that is available on Window 2008 R2 server.
2. Install Window 2008 R2 server on the new RAID.
3. Import your backup into the new installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

For such change the best method is a offline clone copy.

Make sure the disk is recognized and compatible with the controller. For newer standard I would suggest a RAID-6 over a RAID-5, it's a lot safier, especially with a 6 members RAID-5.

- You boot with a clone tool media, copy/clone the entire partition.
- You remove your 6 x 300 GB disk entirely.
- You insert and create the 6 x 3TB array.
- Boot the clone media tool and re-copy the OS on it. The OS size might be limited to change the size for it, but you will have space for other drivers/partitions

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of tools out there to clone an HD:

- You can buy a dock that clones one drive to another. This works well if it's a single drive that's not in RAID. Depending on whether you're doing a file-by-file or bit-by-bit, you may have some issues with sizes of the disks.
- You can use a clone utility like Norton/Symantec Ghost, Acronis, PING, or others. These can make disk or partition based copies of your drive. These also can do file-by-file or bit-by-bit copies.

While the new drive is GPT formatted, it doesn't have to stay that way. You can reformat the drive to use MBR. If you're deliberately trying to convert to GPT, it may be easier to clone the drive as MBR and then convert it to GPT format afterwards.

Truthfully speaking, it may be in your best interests to NOT clone the drive. This is an opportunity to start from scratch on the system and avoid all the old issues. Build a new system, then copy or reinstall the needed items. Windows provides some tools to clone your preferences like the User State Migration Tool (USMT), among others.

Comment: I am not deliberately wanted to convert the new hard disk to GPT, but because the new hard disk is more than 2TB, when I do the partitioning it will automatic convert to GPT. of cause, I can partitioning using MBR format, but the Max capacity that I can used for MBR format is 2TB instead of 12TB then it will be a big wasted.